# Export data from "Identify Results" table to Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, identify

I am working on a street network in QGIS. I needed to increase the resolution of the street segmentation in an area of my network, so I copied and paste this area from another layer.

I selected all features from this network:
[image]

And paste it to my original network:
[image]

The street segmentation is now fine (I got the resolution I wanted in the area I was interested to). The problem is that in the resulting layer, in the areas where the network I pasted overlaps with my original one, I completely lost all of the data in the attribute table.

[image]

As you can see, I selected a random street segment in the overlapping area and the corresponding columns in the attribute table are all NULL.

However, the good news is that the data I wanted to keep (street ID and traffic data TJM_2010) are still present in the Identify Results: 
[image]

Do you know a way to export this data into the attribute table? Since the street segments that now lack information in the attribute table are quite a lot, it would be great if the method was automatic.

Comment: The features that you copied over, did they have similar attribute fields to your original layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joseph has asked, most likely some of your field names between the two layers do not match.  When doing feature copy and paste the field names and order must be exact for attributes to populate correctly.  Here are a few options to remedy this:

- Create the missing fields in the destination table in the order they exist in the other layer/table
- Perform a table join (based on a common id field) between the two tables and field calculate the NULL fields with the related joined field
- Merge the two tables.  This will create a new layer however the fields of both tables should be carried over to the new table